# 14.04 installation - The partiton table format in use on your disk

Tags: partitioning, 14.04

I was trying to upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04 . I made USB disk using Startup disk creator . then restarted and when installing i selected "Upgrade from ubuntu 12.04 LTS to ubuntu 14.04 LTS" . Then i clicked install i got this message 
Here is the image 
[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1zvygcp&s=8#.U1gfYabWE8o)]

And my partiton table looks like this

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l  
Model: ATA WDC WD10JPVT-60A (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B  
Partition Table: gpt  

    Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags  
    1      1049kB  420MB   419MB   ntfs            Ba    hidden  
    2      420MB   693MB   273MB   fat32           EF    boot  
    3      693MB   827MB   134MB                   Mi    msftres  
    8      827MB   10.8GB  10.0GB  linux-swap(v1)  
    9      10.8GB  120GB   109GB   ext4                  msftdata  
    4      120GB   442GB   322GB   ntfs                  msftdata  
    5      442GB   710GB   268GB   ntfs                  msftdata  
    6      710GB   974GB   264GB   ntfs                  msftdata  
    7      974GB   1000GB  25.8GB  ntfs            Ba    hidden, msftdata  


    Model: JetFlash Transcend 16GB (scsi)  
    Disk /dev/sdb: 15.8GB  
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
    Partition Table: msdos  

   Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags  
   1      16.4kB  15.8GB  15.8GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. That message is more informational and you already have the requisite partition, the second one, labeled "boot".

The "boot" partition will be used by grub for your ubuntu uefi files.

Do not confuse this boot partition with the /boot directory / partition used by ubuntu to store the kernel, grub, and other boot files.